# highstock ie8 error

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

Getting an error using Highstock using IE8

```
An Error has occurred in the script on this page
Line: 8
Char: 56
Error: Invalid procedure call or argument
Code: 0
URL: js/highstock.js
```

It works in all other browsers.  How is this fixable?

Comment: How can we help you with just this description ? If you want some answer you should add more details to your question.

Comment: Please prepare example of your chart, because without any code it is not possible to find a reason.

Comment: Sorry guys.  Kinda new to this.  Unfortunately my pages are on a server not exposed to the public yet, but here is a watered down version of one of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/fQZ8B/5/

Comment: I recommend to familair with FAQ http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq where problem in IE7/8 and with tab menu are described

Comment: Sebastian!  You're the best!  Apparently my yAxis settings had a stray comma in them that only alerted older versions of IE.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian Bochan answered this in the comments above.

"The most common reason why a chart works in modern browsers but fails in IE6, 7 and 8, is stray commas in the configuration options. Stray commas are commas after the last item of an object or an array in JavaScript. These will pass silently in modern browsers, but cause a JavaScript error in legacy IE.  For example:"

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
}]
});
```

So check all of your chart settings for any possible strays.  If none are found, try what I did by commenting out settings one-by-one until it runs properly.